# Example in the sprof MAN page is not working

Tags: linux, profiling, glibc, toolchain

I tried using Sprof profiling to test. I tried with the MAN page example: https://github.com/makelinux/examples/tree/master/sprof, but I couldn't see the output as mentioned in the page, I am getting error

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 707: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!


$ sprof -V
sprof (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23
 tried with Glibc-2.18 and 2.19 too
```

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sprof.1.html

Comment: Please provide your code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Code is already present in the manual page

Comment: Ack, thanks. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Thanks Jww, I have just started working on this, So, I logged the error in the forum as some other might have already worked on this. I didn't get any input on that at that time. BTW I will follow the steps mentioned in the link that you sent

Answer (score 3):

This has been reported as a glibc bug here:

- [Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 717: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22380)

It's probably best to continue any further discussion there.

Comment: Sure, I did that

Answer (score 2):

The Bug only occurs with sprof's special loading so simply disabling the assertion when an object is loaded with the sprof flag __RTLD_SPROF allows me to use sprof while avoiding changes that might disturb the normal shared object loading mechanism.  Edit glibc/elf/dl-open.c:707 to:

```
  if (!(__glibc_unlikely (mode & __RTLD_SPROF))) {
   assert (_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT);
  }
```

This works for me with glibc-2.20 and has been posted to https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22380